# how to remove delete button in SwiftUI List rows when in Edit Mode?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

How would remove the delete button in SwiftUI List rows when in Edit Mode? Note the hamburger button on the right of the row that allows rows to be re-ordered needs to continue to function.

Background - Want a list that has the "re-order" rows functions always enabled.  Edit mode seems to enable this (i.e. leave List in edit mode) however do not want the red delete button on each row.

This is a SwiftUI specific question.

EDIT: After removing the delete button only here, so the swipe to delete still works...

Comment: Hi @Greg, did you find solution for your question ?

Comment: No. So I've just assumed it's not possible for the moment

Comment: Hi @Greg, seems this guy found the way,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58770635/5903004

Answer (score 7):

There is a modifier for that, just add '.deleteDisabled(true)'. You can also pass a variable into it making the delete disabled conditionally.

Comment: I was actually after how to remove the delete button only, so the swipe left to delete could still work - if that's possible?

Comment: I believe it is not possible (both in SwiftUI and UIKit), because swipe to delete gesture gets disabled in editing mode not to interfere with the dragging. The red minus button is there as a replacement for the swipe gesture. You could disabled delte in editing mode and leave it as an option otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 11.2, Swift 5.1
Just don't provide onDelete in List and there will be no Delete buttons

Here is example

[image: no delete button]

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var objects = ["1", "2", "3"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(objects, id: \.self) { object in
                    Text("Row \(object)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: relocate)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    func relocate(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        objects.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Alternate approach (with limitations)**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var objects = ["1", "2", "3"]
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode

    var body: some View {
//        NavigationView {
        VStack {
            // !!!  A. using NavigationView instead of VStack above does not work,
            // !!!  because editMode is not updated and always .inactive
            // !!!  B. Also it does not work in Preview, but works in run-time
            EditButton()
            List {

                ForEach(objects, id: \.self) { object in
                    Text("Row \(object)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: relocate)
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
                .deleteDisabled(disableDelete)
            }
//                .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    var disableDelete: Bool {
        if let mode = editMode?.wrappedValue, mode == .active {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func relocate(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        objects.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }

    func delete(from source: IndexSet?) {
        objects.remove(atOffsets: source!)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually after how to remove the delete button only, so the swipe left to delete could still work - if that's possible?

Comment: I've found the approach, which gives visual behaviour like you want, BUT... there are limitations - read in code comments

Comment: Hi @Asperi, does this approach still work for you? I tried it in run time and didn't work. Also tried the new .swipeActions. Any suggestions? Thanks!