# How to allow reordering of rows in a SwiftUI List whist NOT in edit mode?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Is there away to allow reordering of rows in a SwiftUI List whist NOT in edit mode?

That is to give rows a right hand hamburger menu icon which they can use to re-order a row?  (like which is possible in edit mode)

Answer (score 7):

If I understood your question correctly, here is how it is possible to be done:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestEditModeCustomRelocate: View {
    @State private var objects = ["1", "2", "3"]
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .active
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(objects, id: \.self) { object in
                Text("Row \(object)")
            }
            .onMove(perform: relocate)
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    }
    
    func relocate(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        objects.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

Comment: hi - I think that's working because it's in edit mode correct, where I'm after a way to allow one always to re-order, so a way to have "onMove" work when not in edit mode...

Comment: EditMode is just a state value, you need to set it for local list to have row-reordering style. Those things are dependent, no first - no second. Alternate is to code completely custom List-like view.

Comment: ok thanks - so basically not possible - good to know.   I quite like GoApps (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gotasks/id389113399) which is setup like I was referring to and wondering how to get this.  A DIY list to do this would then be quite tricky right, having to hand drag/drop events etc?

Comment: As far as I can see GoApps uses standard reordering activated by Edit button. If this is what you want, it is even simpler - just add anywhere EditButton().

Comment: in the list view of GoApps they seemed to have managed not to have the delete button showing (which is what I was hoping to avoid) and replace this with a check box - not sure if this is possible in SwiftUI?